# Angular form validation with disabled field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have an Angular validation scenario where a field needs to be valid unless it is disabled, in which case it should be ignored.

(I am using `ng-messages` for demo purposes, it doesn't affect the `$errors` state of the form / field).

How do we clear `max` and `required` errors when the field is disabled?

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="disable"> disable field</label><br>

  <input name="width" type="number" ng-disabled="disable" ng-disabled="disable" ng-model="someValue" max="100" required>

  <div class="errors" ng-messages="myForm.width.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Please enter a width</div>
    <div ng-message="max">Width is over the max permitted</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

myForm.$valid = {{ myForm.$valid }}

Here is a working example on JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/supapotoci/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here your input element would be like below using `ng-max` & `ng-required`

**Markup**

```
<input name="width" type="number" ng-disabled="disable" 
ng-model="someValue" ng-max="disable ? false: 100" ng-required="!disable">
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/cubisuheza/1/)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I hadn't realised that `ng-max` would accept a boolean value like that.

Comment: @Ade Thanks :) actually it could be other than number..like `''` / `true` is also working..I didn't aware of it :p

Comment: @downvoter could i know reason behind downvote? it would be good to know where I'm wrong to improvise myself

Answer (score 9):

Solution provided by @pankajparkar is very good.

In case if you don't want any changes in your markup, you can try this.

```
directive('ngDisabled', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var ngModelController = element.controller('ngModel');
            if (!ngModelController) {
                return;
            }
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngDisabled, function (nv, ov) {
                if (nv) { //disabled
                    //reset
                    Object.keys(ngModelController.$validators)
                        .forEach(function (type) {
                            ngModelController.$setValidity(type, true);
                        })
                } else {
                    ngModelController.$validate();
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice approach using directive. +1, could you please explain what `Object` is in you answer. :)

Comment: @pankajparkar thanks for the upvote. `Object` is the global `Object` provided by the browser. Using the `keys` method defined on it we will be able to retrieve the keys defined on a javascript object. `ngModelController.$validators` will contain a map of type of validation and the function to be performed.

Comment: does that would be the same `Object` on cross browser? Would it be present on browser like IE9 & IE 10?

Comment: Yes. IE9+ supports it.

Answer (score 2):

ng-required didn't worked for me with variables mostly because when you use

`ng-required="{{test}}"` the `{{test}}` is returned as string when `ngRequired` expects boolean, luckily you can use it the same way `ngClass` works, if you replace your input with following code it will work

```
<input name="width" type="number" 
  ng-disabled="disable" 
  ng-model="someValue" 
  ng-max="{false: false, true: 100}[!disable]" 
  ng-required="{true : true, false : false}[!disable]" />
```